# LXDE input incredily laggy

Tags: lxde

As of this morning my LXDE keyboard input is unbelievably laggy. I have to very carefully type one character at the time and it can take several seconds for the glyph to appear onscreen. Sometimes I get repeats and sometimes they repeat endlessly. Everything else appears normal. The system is under no strain at all, has 8GB of RAM and the problem occurs with all applications tried so far (Chrome, Thunderbird, LibreOffice Writer, LXTerminal...) even when loaded one at the time. The problem persists across boots  (indeed  is worst right after login). The login manager (password entry screen) does not seem  to suffer from the same problem. I made no modification to my system prior to  the problem arising yesterday but this morning I executed an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` cycle to see if that  might rectify matters. Yesterday I had been testing Hibernation (to no avail) when the problem first arose, [leading me to believe that the issue was related to VM and swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468734/no-swap-partition), but I am increasingly convinced the matter is largely coincidental (maybe I do indeed lack a swap partition, but it should hardly be an issue on a fast, modern machine with oodles of RAM after a fresh reboot). Somebody mentioned stray NFS as a possible source of resource depletion but I am sceptical as I do not have any NFS exports enabled as far as I am aware. Disconnecting the machine from WiFi did not lessen the problem, so in practical terms I doubt it is a network-related issue. As far as I can see I have no runaway processes burning resources, but here is the current output of my `top` list just in somebody can spot something I am missing.

```
Tasks: 195 total,   3 running, 192 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   7689472 total,  1415268 used,  6274204 free,    48268 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   621716 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                    
2265 user     20   0  856168  17980  11016 S   0.7  0.2   0:00.78 lxterminal                                                                                                                                                                 
1402 root      20   0  279148  46736  38736 S   0.3  0.6   0:11.10 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                       
2584 user     20   0   29192   1740   1220 R   0.3  0.0   0:02.49 top                                                                                                                                                                        
   1 root      20   0   34176   3492   1484 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.75 init                                                                                                                                                                       
   2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                                                   
   3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                
   5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                                                               
   7 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.37 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                  
   8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 rcuos/0                                                                                                                                                                    
   9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 rcuos/1                                                                                                                                                                    
  10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.15 rcuos/2                                                                                                                                                                    
  11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 rcuos/3                                                                                                                                                                    
  12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/4                                                                                                                                                                    
  13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/5                                                                                                                                                                    
  14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/6                                                                                                                                                                    
  15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuos/7                                                                                                                                                                    
  16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                                                                     
  17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0                                                                                                                                                                    
  18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1                                                                                                                                                                    
  19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/2                                                                                                                                                                    
  20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/3                                                                                                                                                                    
  21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/4                                                                                                                                                                    
  22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/5                                                                                                                                                                    
  23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/6                                                                                                                                                                    
  24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/7                                                                                                                                                                    
  25 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.62 migration/0                                                                                                                                                                
  28 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.14 migration/1                                                                                                                                                                
  29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                                                
  30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.56 kworker/1:0                                                                                                                                                                
  31 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                                                                                                                                                               
  33 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.39 migration/2                                                                                                                                                                
  34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                                                
  36 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H                                                                                                                                                               
  38 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 migration/3                                                                                                                                                                
  39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                                                                
  41 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H                                                                                                                                                               
  42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                                                                                                    
  43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                                                                  
  44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                                                      
  45 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                                                                                                                                                  
  46 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                                                                                                                
  47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                                                     
  48 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/u17:0                                                                                                                                                              
  49 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                                                                                                    
  50 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                                                                                                    
  51 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                                                                                                                      
  52 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                                                                                                         
  53 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                                                                                                                                                 
  55 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.78 kworker/0:1                                                                                                                                                                
  61 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                                                                                                                 
  62 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0                                                                                                                                                                    
  63 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
```

At present the system is totally unusable and since I need to get it back into working order in time for a business trip on Thursday if I do not find a solution to this (likely trivial) issue I shall be, sadly, forced to totally reinstall in order to circumvent the issue. That of course would be a crying shame but being a total novice I lack the means to identify the problem.

Comment: Plugging the laptop into the power (even though the batter was almost full to begin with) seems to have corrected or at the very least greatly alleviated the problem, even after unplugging it. I do not have any idea what is going on.

Comment: Thinking back, I realise now that a short while ago I was presented with a dialog box offering "desktop" or "laptop" as possible options, that it was set to "desktop", and that I changed it to "laptop". The problem is I have no recollection of what dialog box it was and where it arose, save for having a vague recollection that I triggered it by poking through LXDE-accessible preferences menus. Can somebody maybe think of what setting it was and how I can find the dialog box to revert the change?