# Swap partition get damaged when encrypted

Tags: encryption, swap, ecryptfs

I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I encrypted the home & the swap partition during the installation since it was already encrypted in the old version.

But later I noticed swap partition is not used & using the gparted I found the swaps is damaged, I re-formatted the swap partition as Linux-swap & fixed the UUID in the fstab then cleared the crypttab, then swap was working fine but without the encryption. As soon as I run the ecryptfs-setup-swap to encrypt the swap partition then reboot the system it gets damaged.

This link shows the [steps I followed](http://bit.ly/1prSI4l)

Any idea how to fix this?

---

@muru this is the output, & `sda6` is the swap part.

```
sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="5450-4444" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="DAAC6031AC600A79" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="WinSys" UUID="E2D0647AD0645737" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="96e501a8-40ee-4d08-bcb2-2396a99abd94" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda7: UUID="348874d5-f654-4640-bbad-0b377e545334" TYPE="ext4" 


sudo lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  13.2G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   100G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  42.9G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0  14.3G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 528.2G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Hope its readable now.

Comment: to be honest unless you run a branch of the nsa you should be fine with an unencrypted swap, it really is only an extension of the ram and usually does not have enough of a process stored on it to be that much of a risk

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! There seem to be problems right now with some swap encryption. http://askubuntu.com/questions/91292/is-my-swap-cryptswap-partition-working-properly/109217#109217 , but you could check this as well. http://askubuntu.com/questions/248158/how-do-i-setup-an-encrypted-swap-file

Comment: This what I thought first time when I installed the 14 LTS, when it was released directly, that may be there is problem with the encryption & I left it w/o encrypted swap till now, & now I tried again but same problem, how come this bug (if any) not fixed till now?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it was damaged. Encrypted swap shows up as of type `Unknown` in tools like GParted, because the partition is filled with random data and such tools have no way of knowing that it really is an encrypted swap partition.

Comment: Yes Muru, its Unknown, but why the system is not able to recognize it as soon as I encrypt it. Without running the encryption setup on the swap partition, swap is working fine recognized & utilized by the OS. Also I had setup another new laptop and had no problem encryption works fine on home & swap partition !! I can't figure out what I'm missing in this setup. I already used the encryption for last 2 years with the old Ubuntu versions. Any suggestion.

Comment: I already reformatted the swaps part & now I'm using w/o encryption, so the swapon -s shows this results:Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition 14998524 224 -1

Comment: do you want me to do the encryption on swap then past the swapon -s results?

Comment: yes I know, but cant live without encryption. I'll prepare the data and send it to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: results after encrypting swap & before reboot: -- 
[ sudo cat /etc/crypttab ] 
[ cryptswap1 UUID=6ed3aa70-2d53-4ba7-a03c-034959db49bf /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 ]
[ sudo blkid | grep swap ]
[ /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="9cff2ac3-9bed-438d-829a-2b97f91da0d1" TYPE="swap" ]
[ sudo swapon -s ]
[ Filename         Type  Size         Used Priority ]
[ /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 partition 14998524 836612 -1 ]

Comment: now results after reboot:
[ sudo cat /etc/crypttab ]
[ cryptswap1 UUID=6ed3aa70-2d53-4ba7-a03c-034959db49bf /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 ]
[ sudo blkid | grep swap ]
[ No data available ]
[ sudo swapon -s ]
[ No data available ] swap not working

Comment: Also if I run swapon -a I get this [ swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory ]

Comment: @Adscnet @Adscnet does `sudo blkid | grep 6ed` show anything?

Comment: doesn't show anything

Comment: @Adscnet so the base partition for cryptswap got its uuid changed. Try looking up the UUID of the partition and replacing the old value in crypttab.

Comment: when I run blkid, I don't see the swap UUID coz the partition as I said before its unknown to the system

Comment: @Adscnet don't look for swap in blkid. Try to identify by other means, like partition number or identifier (`sdaX`).

Comment: Iam not able to do anything with this partition not even mounting it to get the UUID

Comment: @Adscnet can you post the output of `sudo blkid` and `lsblk` in your question? Not in the comments, it's really hard to understand output in the comments.